# Python's Tkinter's iconify not working on Fedora

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, fedora, customtkinter

This code is used to hide or dock the current window, and then create a new window using `CTkTopLevel`, and then to automatically undock or bring back the previous window to the screen. This seems to work on OSX perfectly, but when I try it on my Fedora machine, it fails to undock? Any reason why?

This is the code, called in both machines.

```
def CreateNewAccount(self):

        #hide the previous window // seems to only work on OSX well
        self.iconify()

        #create new window
        window = customtkinter.CTkToplevel(self)
        window.title("Project")
        window.geometry("1200x800")
        window.resizable(False, False)

        window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.deiconify())
```

It should automatically undock and dock when deleting the window, tried other things like withdraw and it didn't work. Sometimes got a bug where after deleting the second tab, it would stay there as an unreactive tab and would only disappear after I closed the whole program.

Comment: Note that `window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.deiconify())` will execute `self.deiconify()` immediately.  It should be `window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.deiconify)` instead.

Comment: Also why are you hiding one window and then show another one? Isn't it better to reuse the first window?

Comment: @acw1668 when you do this it creates the bug of the window just remaining as a unreative window that cant be deleted.

Comment: @TheLizzard I want to make multiple instances of the same window.